# Extract Web Elements from an E-Commerce website?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, aliexpress

I m trying write a code to access Aliexpress and search for an item, then extract the details, such as, Product name, price, etc.; on page by page to an Excel document. I seek through previous questions posted here to build it. Thanks to that.

Somehow I was able to search the item for first 5 or 6 test runs but then suddenly, Aliexpress asked me to either login or register.

1.) First question, Why any browser won't access the website without registering? Did they recognized my user-agent?

2.) Secondly, Then I was wrote a code to auto log in. Site contains lots of Javascripts, an it is an responsive site. Some html elements appear as we click them. When in the auto log in, my code won't detect the either E-mail or password elements of the page. Is there something preventing it from been detected? How can I solve this?

I here put my sample code:

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

    //To input the user's search
    Scanner nw1 = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("What do you want to search?");
    String a = nw1.nextLine();

    //Open the driver
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", 
    "E:\\JetBrains\\webdriver\\chrome\\chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver AE = new ChromeDriver();

    //Open the web page and Login in.
    AE.get("https://www.aliexpress.com/");
    Thread.sleep(2000);

    //xpath of account button
    AE.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id="nav-user-account"]/div/div/p[3]/a[2]")).click();

    //xpath of Sign in button
    AE.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[9]/a")).click();
    AE.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    //xpath of Email box 
    AE.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"fm-login-id\"]")).sendKeys("my-email");

    //xpath of password section to type  
    AE.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\'fm-login-password\']")).sendKeys("my-password");
    AE.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    // xpath of submit button
    AE.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id="login-form"]/div[5]/button")).click()
```

Sry kind of my first time here. 
Any helpful comments are welcome. Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you login through https://login.aliexpress.com/ ?

Comment: @DebanjanB Yes I could. But I m hoping to share this code with few of my friends. So I want input login details in the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

It is because following x path in not clicking on account button instead it is clicking on sign in button

```
AE.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id="nav-user-account"]/div/div/p[3]/a[2]")).click();
```

find element through id. Id is available to click on account

```
"nav-user-account"
```

while clicking verify that it is unfold through following class

```
"ng-item nav-pinfo-item nav-user-account user-account-unfold"
```

if unfold contain than box is open otherwise it is close. If close than click on it. 
Try this one first.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. "nav-user-account" is working fine and code right after, to click the sign in button is functioning as well. Question comes when entering the details in the sign in sub window. No matter how I get the element(css_selector or xpath or id or etc.) code won't detect it.

Answer (score 0):

1. Try applying delete cookies ,some sites access data from cache /cookies ,clearing it would solve.Also quit driver at the end of your script and open a new instance i.e driver.manage().deleteAllCookies(); and driver.quit();
2. xpath in your code needs to be corrected as  AE.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='nav-user-account']/div/div/p[3]/a[2]")).click();
   Use single quotes inside of your xpaths.

Comment: By adding double quotes or single haven't made any difference. Both worked fine. But the problem is when the sign-in window appeared, none of the elements on that windows is detected?.